# Replacing HTML in correct div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a few divs which are generated automagically from a php loop.

```
<div class="link_0"><a href=# onclick="getLink('20120922','0');">Get Link</a></div>
<div class="link_1"><a href=# onclick="getLink('20120922','1');">Get Link</a></div>
<div class="link_2"><a href=# onclick="getLink('20120922','2');">Get Link</a></div>
```

I'm trying to use jQuery to replace the correct div the user click on with the content from another php query.

```
function getLink(thisDate, i)
{
    $.post("json.php?page=ajax", { date: thisDate },
        function(data) {
            ('.link_'+i).html(data);
    });  
}
```

I'm at my wits end trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok! not related to context but You're sending `page=ajax` that's a `get` param and also `date` as one `post` param, that's strange.. Also missing the `jQuery/$` in the post callback!

Comment: I'm calling the same page, so I'm using get to seperate between the main display and the jquery fetching. The date param isn't the actual value. Just used that so it could be posted here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the dollar sign ($(...))! ;-)

```
$('.link_'+i).html(data);
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it would something simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.link_'+i).html(data);
```

you are missing $